# Doubt in a step given in a document on Exact Differential Equations

Tags: calculus

I was reading the following  link, http://www.math.wustl.edu/~minbaili/IFM.pdf, and encountered a step that is giving me some trouble. This is on Page 4/5, Example number 0.5, and the line is given below

> Do Integration, we can get a general solution,

Could anyone clarify what exactly is being integrated and how? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration is the usual technique as you saw earlier in separation of variables problems. Let $u = xy$ and then the DEqn is simply $du/u^2 = 2dx/x^5$ hence integrate both sides to obtain $-1/u = -2/4x^4+ C$. But, $u = xy$ thus, after reciprocating both sides, we obtain:
$$xy = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2x^4}-C} = \frac{2x^4}{1-2Cx^4}$$
thus
$$ y = \frac{2x^3}{1-2Cx^4}$$
do you understand why my answer is the same as that given in the linked pdf?